# Select from the same table with two columns

Tags: sql

I have a table ("MyOrders") with two columns ("user_id" and "order_id")

What could be the shortest SELECT command to return the list of all users who have 10 or more orders?

I tried this

```
SELECT MyOrders.user_id, MyOrders.order_id 
FROM MyOrders 
WHERE orders >= 10;
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> Oracle... please tag a **single** rdbms

Comment: Did it work? Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

```
SELECT MyOrders.user_id, count(MyOrders.order_id) as cnt
FROM MyOrders
GROUP BY  MyOrders.user_id
HAVING cnt>=10;
```

Answer (score 0):

[lucumt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3176419/lucumt) is correct.

Just to make it a bit better, you can use this.

```
SELECT MyOrders.user_id as `User ID`, count(MyOrders.order_id) as `Orders 
Count`
FROM MyOrders
GROUP BY  MyOrders.user_id
HAVING `Orders Count` >= 10
ORDER BY `Orders Count` DESC;
```

This query would not count the orders if order_id is empty or null. If you want to count them though even when the order_id is empty/null, you can just count user_id instead of order_id.

```
SELECT MyOrders.user_id as `User ID`, count(MyOrders.user_id) as `Orders Count`
FROM MyOrders
GROUP BY  MyOrders.user_id
HAVING `Orders Count` >= 10
ORDER BY `Orders Count` DESC;
```